# React and localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm making a blog with posts that can be liked and saved to localstorage.

I get posts from api.

When you like, the color and the number of likes change. The function itself works. But when I like one post, after refreshing the page, all posts get likes. That is, localstorage does not work correctly, I think.
For a long time I tried to fix it myself, but it turns out to be done. I hope for your help, friends.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import './BlogList.scss';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';

function BlogList({
  key,
  title,
  tagList,
  favoritesCount,
  createdAt,
  description,
  favorited,
  authorUserName,
  authorImage,
}) {
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = React.useState(() => {
    const saved = localStorage.getItem('likeCount');
    const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
    return initialValue || favoritesCount;
  });
  const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(() => {
    const saved = localStorage.getItem('liked');
    const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
    return initialValue || favorited;
  });

  const likePost = () => {
    setLiked(!liked);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    setLikeCount(liked ? likeCount - 1 : likeCount + 1);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('likeCount', JSON.stringify(likeCount));
    localStorage.setItem('liked', JSON.stringify(liked))
  });
  const heartFill = liked ? 'crimson' : 'currentColor';
  const createDate = format(new Date(createdAt), 'MMMM d, uu');
  return (
    <div key={key} className="blog-frame">
      <div className="blog-frame__content">
        <div className="blog-article">
          <h5>{title}</h5>
          <button type="button" className="like-btn" onClick={likePost}>
            <FavoriteBorderIcon style={{ fill: heartFill }} />
          </button>
          <p className="like-count">
            {likeCount}
          </p>
        </div>
        {tagList.map((tag, idx) => {
          return <button key={`${tag}-${idx}`} type="button" className="btn-blog-tag">{tag}</button>
        })}
        <p className="blog-frame__text">
          {description}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="blog-frame__profile">
        <div className="profile-article">
          <h6>{authorUserName}</h6>
          <p className="profile-date">{createDate}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="profile-avatar"><img src={authorImage} alt="avatar" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BlogList;
```

I liked one post:[image]

After refreshing the page:
[image]

My BlogContent component where my props are located

```
import React from 'react';
import BlogList from '../BlogList/BlogList';
import useFetchData from '../../services/useFetchData';
import './BlogContent.scss';

function BlogContent() {
  const { posts } = useFetchData();

  const dataposts = posts.map((post, index) => {
    return (
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <BlogList
          post={post}
          title={post.title}
          tagList={post.tagList}
          favoritesCount={post.favoritesCount}
          createdAt={post.createdAt}
          description={post.description}
          favorited={post.favorited}
          authorUserName={post.author.username}
          authorImage={post.author.image}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="blog-list-wrapper">
      {dataposts}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogContent;
```

I get posts from useFetchData:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useFetchData = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data: response } = await axios.get('http://kata.academy:8022/api/articles');
        setPosts(response.articles);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return {
    posts,
  };
};

export default useFetchData;
```

I apologize for such details. Made everything clear to you. Thanks.

Comment: Well. Yes. `likeCount` is a number. You aren't storing any data about which post it applies to. How did you expect to tell what the count was for?

Comment: pass unique key to bloglist <BlogList key = {index} > and in blog List component create unique local storage key

Comment: i think you should use array of like count

Comment: @zainuldin adding index to <BlogList> did not help

Comment: by index, every component have it's unique local storage key

Comment: @zainuldin got this in console: Warning: BlogList: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop

Comment: @zainuldin Yes, sure

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a pair of like counts and their respective ID. Right now you are just saving the like count and repopulating it in UI. Your code has no logic of how to determine which likes are for which posts.

```
// Try something like this
const mapoflikes = {};
// increase mapofLikes
mapofLikes[id] = mapofLikes[id]+1 ?? 1
// save this to localstorage
// retrieve this from localstorage.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Pass `[ likeCount , liked ]` to dependence list of `useEffect`.By this every time the state changes it'll update the value in local storage. Load local storage only once whenever the page is rendered. Have a look at this code example

```
const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = React.useState('')
const [liked , setLiked] = React.useState('') 
   
 useEffect(()=>{ 
   // calls only once
   setLikeCount('localStorageVal')
   setLiked ('localStorageVal')
 }, [ ] )

 useEffect(()=>{ 
    // saves to local storage
 }, [ liked , likeCount ] )
```

Comment: I did not quite understand. Do we write anything in React.useState? And should there be one key for liked and likeCount? localStorageVal?

Comment: Do you have multiple components using like functionality?

Comment: I mean list of BlogList?

Comment: if you have multiple blogList components then you can use unique local storage key for each component like so, you're localStorageKey+key (props.key)

Comment: I have updated my post, please take a look. Maybe that will make it easier for you to understand my problem.